# How do i create methods from the parsed values from the xml file

Tags: java, xml

I have parsed an xml file  using the digester parser  , now i need to create a method like

If I have a

```
              <productlist>
                  <products> </products>
                  .
                  ..

              </productlist>
```

findProducts() should give me all the subelements with all the attributes

How do i do this ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming Java... try this:

```
 digester.addObjectCreate("productlist", ArrayList.class);
 digester.addCallMethod("productlist/products", "add", 1);
 digester.addCallParam("productlist/products", 0);
```

Comment: thnks for the answer i m using java itself ,i got wat u said ,but plz can u elaborate it ,wat do i do in add() to get all the subelements content

Comment: I don't understand your question.